# Excel unable to access file

Tags: excel, vba

Just doing something at work, and trying to reference a file on a network directory on VBA.

```
Sub CostPriceMain()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.DisplayAlerts = False


NewFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Files 
(*.xlsx; *.xls), (*.xlsx; *.xls), All Files, *.*", FilterIndex:=1)


If NewFile = False Then Exit Sub

If NewFile <> False Then

Set wkbk = Workbooks.Open(NewFile)

End If



Dim Sh As Worksheet
For Each Sh In wkbk.Worksheets
    If Sh.Visible = True Then
        Sh.Activate
        Sh.Cells.Copy
        Workbooks("S:\Stafford\WK24 WH.xls").Sheets("Name").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
    End If
Next Sh
Application.CutCopyMode = False



ActiveWorkbook.Close True


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Application.DisplayAlerts = True


Done = MsgBox("Task Complete", vbOKOnly)

End Sub
```

I'm trying to open it so that that I can paste data from wkbk into it. However I keep getting a 'Microsoft Office Excel cannot access the file' runtime error 1004.

Is this an issue because the file is not stored locally? As I'm scratching my head at this.

Comment: Having 2 visible sheets would open the file 2 times... is that a wanted behavior? Also you do copy the the whole sheet without pasting... is that also correct?

Comment: One reason for a 1004 is the file is already open.. you don't appear to close the file in your loop, which means for every sheet in `wkbk.Worksheets` present, Excel attempts to open the file. When your error occurs, is WK24.xls open?

Comment: I should have said that wkbk is a different file that I am trying to copy data from. But know the file isn't open when it ends.

Comment: Have updated to show the full text

Comment: Things would be a lot less confusing without the variables being so similarly named? `wkbk` and `wrkbk`? Is that intentional? Try calling them `SourceWkb` and `TargetWkb` or similar..?

Comment: @CLR But that shouldn't mean it won't be working. But I get where you are coming from.

Comment: Just checking.. you don't have WK24.xls open, but hidden somewhere do you?

Comment: No it is not open anywhere at the moment.

Comment: I'm starting to think it's your filename - originally you had `WK24.xls` and now it's `WK24 WH.xls`.

Comment: Yea that was just due to a typo on my part!

Answer (score 0):

You open your workbook within the loop which means it will try and open it for every sheet - and throw an error when it's already open.

Open the workbook before you start looping and then just reference it.  This code will copy each visible sheet from the workbook containing the code to WK24.xls (note, no activating of sheets required):

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wrkBk As Workbook
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open("S:\Stafford\WK24.xls")

    For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If wrkSht.Visible Then


            'Copy sheet.
            wrkSht.Copy After:=wrkBk.Sheets(wrkBk.Sheets.Count)
        End If
    Next wrkSht

End Sub
```

**Edit:**

I've made a few changes to your posted code.
I removed `If NewFile = False Then Exit Sub` - If NewFile isn't false it will run the code, otherwise it jumps straight to the end.  It provides a single exit point for your procedure.
I updated `ActiveWorkbook.Close True` to your referenced workbooks.  `ActiveWorkbook` may not always be the correct book - always best to avoid Active or Select... if you find yourself using either (or Activate or Selected or anything similar) then you're probably making more work for yourself.
Your `MsgBox` isn't going to act on any response, it's just informing you so no need to set it to a variable.

If you're still finding it says the workbook isn't accessible then triple check the file location, file name, whether it's already open.
Which file is causing the problem?  NewFile or WK24?

Also - are you copying the whole sheet, cells from the sheet, copy & pastespecial - you keep changing your code.

```
Sub CostPriceMain()

    Dim NewFile As Variant
    Dim wkbk As Workbook
    Dim wrkBk As Workbook
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    NewFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Files     (*.xlsx; *.xls), (*.xlsx; *.xls), All Files, *.*", FilterIndex:=1)

    If NewFile <> False Then

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        Set wkbk = Workbooks.Open(NewFile)
        Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open("S:\Stafford\WK24.xls")

        For Each wrkSht In wkbk.Worksheets
            If wrkSht.Visible Then
                'Copy all cells with formula, etc.
                'wrkSht.Cells.Copy Destination:=wrkBk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

                'Copy and pastespecial all cells.
                'wrkSht.Cells.Copy
                'wrkBk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

                'Copy whole sheet to WK2 (Sheets includes ChartSheets)
                wrkSht.Copy After:=wrkBk.Sheets(wrkBk.Sheets.Count)
            End If
        Next wrkSht

        wrkBk.Close True  'Closes WK24.
        wkbk.Close False 'Closes your chosen file without saving.

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        MsgBox "Task Complete", vbOKOnly
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting the same error. In my code wkbk was actually a different file that I opened earlier with Application.GetOpenFilename, and I am trying to copy data from the file, into the file I am trying to open above. But I still keep getting the no access message.

Comment: I know that wrkSht.Copy After copies the sheet to after, could it be modified to paste the data from the source sheet ontop of the target one?

Comment: I've updated the code to show how to paste the cells either through a straight copy/paste or copy/pastespecial.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub CostPriceMain()

Dim SourceWkb As Workbook
Dim TargetWkb As Workbook
Dim SourceWksht As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

NewFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Files     (*.xlsx; *.xls), (*.xlsx; *.xls), All Files, *.*", FilterIndex:=1)

If NewFile = False Then Exit Sub
If NewFile <> False Then
    Set SourceWkb = Workbooks.Open(NewFile)
End If

Set TargetWkb = Workbooks.Open("S:\Stafford\WK24.xls") ' warning - XLS file could cause problems - see note

For Each SourceWksht In SourceWkb.Worksheets
    If SourceWksht.Visible Then
        SourceWksht.Copy After:=TargetWkb.Sheets(TargetWkb.Sheets.Count)
    End If
Next SourceWksht

TargetWkb.Close True
SourceWkb.Close False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Done = MsgBox("Task Complete", vbOKOnly)

End Sub
```

I notice your "wk24" is an `XLS`file, yet you invite the user to choose `XLS`or `XLSX` files to import from. You can't import an `XLSX` file into an `XLS` file using this method. I'd suggest changing your target file to  `WK24.XLSX`

Comment: WK24 is xls, but in the first part they could copy the data from an xlsx file is they desired. :) Just gonna try this in a minute!

Comment: Still getting the no access issue. Which is annoying as I can see that no one else has it open, and the directory is correct.

Comment: FYI, I created a WK24.xls**x** file and used the above to import an external file into it without any problem. Perhaps it's a problem local to you?

Comment: I was curious as to whether this is effected by that fact I am trying to read a file from the D:\ drive, which is on a network?

Comment: It didn't cause an issue for me. All my files are on shared network drives. Can you open the file manually?

Comment: Your method actually works nearly perfectly, it is finding the file now perfectly. It is creating the data on a new sheet though, how could I modify so the data of the sourcesheet is pasted onto the target one?

Comment: You'd just need to alter the `.Copy` part to pick up the `UsedRange` of the source and then specify the destination based on the bottom of the Target's `UsedRange`. It would be a separate question to this one though - and I suspect someone has already asked if you have a look.